# How big is a paragraph in C

Tags: c, dos

I'm looking at MS DOS Headers with C. I am trying to find the end of the header, and in the documentation there is [this](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/app/util/bin/format/mz/DOSHeader.html):

```
 WORD   e_cparhdr;                   // Size of header in paragraphs
```

I am unfamiliar with what a paragraph is exactly. Is it a defined set of words? and does that definition change on different systems i.e. 32-64 bit.

Comment: Can you provide more context?

Comment: I wonder if I this doc means pages as in memory

Comment: What are "MS DOS Headers"? Are you talking about the header of an MS-DOS `.exe` file? If you are, then you may want to specify this clearly in the question (even if it is apparent from the link that you posted).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, it is for an .exe file, so a PE header with the magic number MZ.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, I believe that is the answer. I also had the same issue as that poster, you type in paragraph and all you get is programs on how to analyse paragraphs.

Comment: Notes on the format of DOS .EXE files
http://www.tavi.co.uk/phobos/exeformat.html

> The term paragraph refers to a size of 16 bytes (this is derived from the way that memory segmentation is implemented). PS. This was meant to be an answer,  alas after closing the question answering became impossible.